# React js want to loop through react select multiple pages instead of concat each page

Tags: reactjs, formik

Currently i have created a select drop down which calls on all created features of page 1 & page 2 with the use of concat, i want to make this process dynamic so that instead of typing each page to refer for the Select drop down, guess including a looping process would make this function dynamic. could some one tell me how to implement this.

the default page items per page is 20.

```
const GeneralInputFormBlock = ({ formik, isEdit }) => {
 const classes = useStyle();
 const { touched, errors } = formik;
 const [features, setFeatures] = useState([]);

const loadFeature = async () => {
 let page1 = await search({
  _entity: 'Feature',
  featureCode: 'FTR',
  _select: 'featureCode,id',
  _page: 1,
});

let page2 = await search({
  _entity: 'Feature',
  _select: 'featureCode,id',
  featureCode: 'FTR',
  _page: 2,
});

const allRules = page1.data.concat(page2.data);
setFeatures(allRules);
};

return (
<GridItem xs={8}>
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel>Feature Ids*</InputLabel>
          <Select
            multiple
            input={<Input id="select-feature-ids" />}
            renderValue={selected => (
              <div className={classes.chips}>
                {selected.map(value => (
                  <Chip
                    key={value}
                    label={
                      features.length &&
                      features.filter(f => f.id === value)[0].featureCode
                    }
                    className={classes.chip}
                  />
                ))}
              </div>
            )}
            {...formik.getFieldProps('featureIds')}
          >
            {features.map(({ featureCode, id }) => (
              <MenuItem key={featureCode} value={id}>
                {featureCode}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>

          {errors.featureIds && touched.featureIds && (
            <Error msg={errors.featureIds} />
          )}
        </FormControl>
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  </GridItem>
</Card>
);
};
```

Comment: Are there a static number of pages or some kind of "end of data" indicator?

Comment: No, currently i have only created feature contents for only 2 pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use a for loop or while loop? You'll need to determine how you'll know when you're done fetching to figure out which option is the better fit.

```js
for(let i = 1; i < numOfPages; i++) {
  let page = await search({
    _entity: 'Feature',
    featureCode: 'FTR',
    _select: 'featureCode,id',
    _page: i,
  });
  setFeatures(features.concat(page));
}
```

```js
let page = [];
let counter = 1;
while(page) {
  page = await search({
    _entity: 'Feature',
    featureCode: 'FTR',
    _select: 'featureCode,id',
    _page: counter,
  });
  setFeatures(features.concat(page));
  counter++;
}
```

Comment: used the while loop getting "Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function"

Comment: put the loop inside your async `loadFeatures` function instead of the 2 separate awaits